# How to use ASTMatcher on a project

Tags: clang

I have written a ASTMatcher to find all global variables in a project. Now I can find all the global variables in a single file (.cpp or .h), but I have no idea how to use my ASTMatcher on a project. It cannot find variables in the included files instructed by cmakelists. How can I solve it ? Using scan-build or adding command line arguments in my ASTMatcher ? (I'm sorry about my English...)

/**********************************************************************/

I used my ASTMatcher to check its own source file,  and it can find all the global variables I defined in it.Showed like this:

```
{
"GlobalVar":[ 
{
    "name" : "MyToolCategory", 
    "type" : "int", 
    "loc" : "D:\\LLVM\\llvm\\tools\\clang\\tools\\extra\\match-global-variable\\MatchGlobalVariable.cpp:22:33"
},
{
    "name" : "MoreHelp", 
    "type" : "int", 
    "loc" : "D:\\LLVM\\llvm\\tools\\clang\\tools\\extra\\match-global-variable\\MatchGlobalVariable.cpp:30:22"
},
{
    "name" : "GlobalVarMatcher", 
    "type" : "int", 
    "loc" : "D:\\LLVM\\llvm\\tools\\clang\\tools\\extra\\match-global-variable\\MatchGlobalVariable.cpp:51:20"
},
{
    "name" : "GlobalVar", 
    "type" : "int", 
    "loc" : "D:\\LLVM\\llvm\\tools\\clang\\tools\\extra\\match-global-variable\\MatchGlobalVariable.cpp:55:12"
}
]
```

}

But errors occurs
[picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G77Fi.png)

I wrote my ASTMatcher referencing `http://bcain-llvm.readthedocs.io/projects/clang/en/latest/LibASTMatchersTutorial/`

Comment: Hi, you're english is great, no worries! Could you provide more information such as output from your tool or perhaps important parts of it's source?

Comment: Thank you, and I have updated my questions.